# Forecasting using ARMAX(0,2) model yields identical results regardless of exogenous variable array being passed

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm using the statsmodels ARMA functionality to produce a forecast using an ARMAX(0,2) model with 1 exogenous variable and am getting counterintuitive results.

Regardless of the exogenous variables passed to exog in the forecast function (e.g. arma_res.forecast(steps=5, **exog**=f_exog)), an identical forecast array is returned except for the last element.

For example:

```
arparams = np.array([0])
maparams = np.array([.65, .35])

arparams = np.r_[1, -arparams]
maparam = np.r_[1, maparams]
nobs = 250
y = arma_generate_sample(arparams, maparams, nobs)

exog = np.random.normal(size=nobs)

arma_mod = sm.tsa.ARMA(y, order=(0, 2), exog=exog)
arma_res = arma_mod.fit(trend='nc', disp=-1)

# Exogenous vars for forecasts
f_exog = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
f_exog_2 = [x * 5 for x in f_exog]

forecast_1 = arma_res.forecast(steps=5, exog=f_exog)[0]
forecast_2 = arma_res.forecast(steps=5, exog=f_exog_2)[0]
```

Produces forecasts of:

```
array([-0.0884847 , -0.03223685, -0.00190045, -0.00860229,  0.0987421 ])
array([-0.0884847 , -0.03223685, -0.00190045, -0.00860229,  0.49371049])
```

A notebook with the setup for this is here: https://github.com/dbrodSq/ARMA_Test/blob/master/Statsmodels_forecast_example.ipynb

The above pattern holds regardless of the "steps" parameter. Does anyone have an idea of why?

I believe that ARMAX forecasting for multiple periods is possible with Statsmodels and I don't believe similar problems as above occur as long as k_ar != 0 (i.e. there's at least one AR parameter).

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious and thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Are you using statsmodels 0.6.1? There might have been some bugfixes in forecasting for ARMA with exog since then.

Comment: I was indeed!  Using the most recent version made the above problem go away. Thanks so much!